# QueryDSL Handle result

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to handle the result of a query list, but when I attempt to run the following code:

```
SimpleExpression<?>[] selectClause = buildSelectClause();
PathBuilder<?>[] fromClause = buildFromClause();
Predicate[] whereClause = buildWhereClause();

Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
HibernateQuery query = new HibernateQuery(session);

List<Tuple> result = query.from( fromClause )
        .where( whereClause )
        .list( new QTuple(selectClause) );
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.mysema.query.jpa.hibernate.HibernateQuery.from([Lcom/mysema/query/types
/EntityPath;)Lcom/mysema/query/jpa/JPQLQueryBase;
```

This makes no sense for me, I'm using querydsl-jpa.3.2.4. Does anyone know whats happening?

Comment: This looks like you have conflicting dependencies on your classpath. The code compiles, but you get a exception at runtime?

Comment: yes it's at runtime. I'm using hibernate 3.0.

Comment: Make sure you have no other Querydsl versions on your classpath.

Comment: I checked the classpath and cleaned the project but the problem persists

Comment: No idea what else could be wrong, the signature is definitely ok, I tested query.from(PathBuilder[]) myself now, and it worked.

Comment: Timo, you were right, it was my mistake, I had a conflict dependency in my project, too bad for me! thanks for the help.